# Why function not displaying value in php

Tags: php, jquery, oop

I am trying to getting the value of variable inside the function defined in Shot_code.php.

Outside the class the value is showing, but i am getting blank output when trying to get it inside the function and there is no any syntax error.

What's going wrong with it?

Shot.php

```
<?php
include './Shot_code.php';

$cart_class = new Cart_Class(isset($_POST['ID']));

?>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.getSrc').click(function() {
                var src = $(this).attr('src');
                var id =    $(this).attr('id');
                var specific =   $('.showPic').attr('src');
                var specific = src;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Shot.php",
                    data: {"ID":id},
                    success: function(result){
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <body>

    <div  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' id='single_product'  
          class='col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12'>
        <img src="images/kabootar.jpg" class="getSrc" id="5">
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
          <img src="" class="showPic">
            <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

              <?php 
                $cart_class->cart_head_info_print();

              ?>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>    
    </body>
```

Shot_code.php

```
<?php
    // Here if(isset) returning value
    class Cart_Class{           
        public $aho;

        public function __construct($id) 
        {
            $this->aho = $id;
        }

        function cart_head_info_print(){   
            echo $this->aho;
            //Here nothing is displaying
        }    
    }
```

Comment: @jszobody
Code is indented properly , i think there's not any issue in reading syntax

Comment: Are you instantiating your class? e.g. `include "Shot_code.php"; $cart_class = new Cart_Class($id);`

Comment: @BenM.
See my updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isset()` will return boolean instead of `POST['ID']`. Also, PHP won't recognize it since you're not telling the `Cart_Class` needs to instantiated once post request comes.

It would better written like this

```
<?php
include './Shot_code.php';

if (isset($_POST['ID'])) {
    $cart_class = new Cart_Class($_POST['ID']);
    $cart_class->cart_head_info_print();
    exit();
}
....
....
```

Then grab the result and perform js logic

Comment: After adding this code i am still not  getting the value in Modal Header. It's still returning blank output

Comment: Of course, you need to **get** the output through jQuery -- say -- success callback then **set** it to anywhere as you like, i.e `$('.modal-header').html('result')`

Comment: Worked for me !
Superb !
God Bless you !